# Tracking the number of recursive calls without using global variables in Python

Tags: python, recursion

How to track the number of recursive calls without using global variables in Python. For example, how to modify the following function to keep track the number of calls?

```
def f(n):
    if n == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return n * f(n-1)

print f(5)
```

Comment: All calls ever? That's global by definition. Or are you interested in the number of calls still in progress at a given point in time? That ought to be doable, though only with some introspection.

Comment: How is the information (call count) to be retrieved?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As delnan said, if you want all calls *ever*, it's impossible without a global, so I'm assuming you just want the call *depth*, for which you just need to add a return value

```
def f(n):
    if n == 1:
        return 1,0
    else:
        x, call_depth= f(n-1)
        return n * x, call_depth+1
```

If you're dealing with several recursive calls, you can do a `max(call_depth1, call_depth2)` (depth of longest call tree) or just sum the two (total number of actual calls)

Comment: it's not impossible without a global, see my answer below.

Comment: @goncalopp It seems to me that this answer can give me the total number of calls ever, which is what I need, so why do you mention it is impossible?

Comment: goncalopp: This gives an answer that is off-by-one because call depth is not the same as number of calls.

Comment: @martineau Yes I notice this point. Still, I can get either total number of calls or call depth by using this kind of method.

Comment: @snow: When others say "total number of calls" they mean if you explicitly call it more than once, say `f(3)` then another line with `f(4)`, that you want the total number from each of these two calls added together.

Comment: @snow: So is that what you meant when you said it or did you mean just the number for any given call for a number `n`?

Answer (score 10):

Here's a neat trick that doesn't use a global: you can stash the counter in the function itself.

```
def f(n):
    f.count += 1
    if n == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return n * f(n-1)
```

After which:

```
>>> f.count = 0 # initialize the counter
>>> f(5)
120
>>> f.count
5
>>> f(30)
265252859812191058636308480000000L
>>> f.count
35
```

This handles the "all calls ever" case, anyhow.

Comment: that's a cool trick, but isn't `f.count` a global too, [by definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_variable)? Is this better than passing a reference in a argument, somehow?

Comment: IMO the initialization of f.count to 0 makes this quite an ugly (and confusing) solution.

Comment: @goncalopp well I guess *technically* it's not global - the variable is an attribute of f, however it still carries all the problems of a global.

Comment: @goncalopp: `count` isn't in `globals()`, so there's certainly a defensible definition of "global" which makes it not one.  @MikeVella: I'm not a fan of hacking function attributes myself, and would never use it in production code, but I find `f.count = 0` the *least* confusing part of this.  I certainly find it less ugly than the `hasattr` checks I would need otherwise, but beauty is in the eye of the beholder, I guess.

Comment: My answer is there to show that there *is* a way to track the number of calls *ever* without a global. I agree it is ugly. I consider @goncalopp's solution to be the most elegant. My solution also doesn't require the user to initialize the variable, which I think makes the behaviour more "as expected".

Comment: You could probably use a default argument to initialize `f.count` -- e.g. if the default argument is `None` then set `f.count` to 1, otherwise set `f.count` to the value of the default argument (making sure to add the default argument to the call when you recurse of course)...  That's a little nicer than `hasattr` (which you need to explicitly delete the count attribute later if you want it to work a for a second pass ...)

Comment: `f.count` is an attribute of the global variable `f` (which is the function object), so it's not entirely clear that doing it this way satisfies the requirement of not using a global variables.

Answer (score 6):

This method will give you the *total* number of times the function has run:

```
def f(n):
    if hasattr(f,"count"):
        f.count += 1
    else:
        f.count = 1
    if n == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return n * f(n-1)
```

Comment: Problem: Only one call to `f()` will count correctly. You should probably reset the attribute before returning 1.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a way that uses the stack instead of global variables. As shown it tallies the number of calls to the function including the initial one, not just the number of recursive calls the function made to itself. To make it do that, just move the `ncalls += 1` to the beginning of the `else` statements.

```
def f(n, ncalls=0):
    ncalls += 1
    if n == 1:
        return 1, ncalls
    else:
        res, ncalls = f(n-1, ncalls)
        return n * res, ncalls

for n in xrange(1, 6):
    print 'f({}): {:4d} ({} calls)'.format(n, *f(n))
```

Output:

```
f(1):    1 (1 calls)
f(2):    2 (2 calls)
f(3):    6 (3 calls)
f(4):   24 (4 calls)
f(5):  120 (5 calls)
```

Comment: beautiful, wish I'd thought of that!

Comment: The number of calls being same as initial value of `n` is only true for this particular example. So I prefer your original answer better.

Comment: snow: OK, I removed the alternative in the update and simplified the original.

Answer (score 0):

You could add an argument to keep count of the calls in (would need to be something mutable), where it gets incremented at the start of the function.