# How many unique numbers will be printed on the screen when f(0) is called?

Tags: python, recursion

I've been trying to solve a problem (I'm new to recursion) and here's the given code:

```
def f(n):
    print(n)
    if (0 <= n) and (n <= 1000000000):
        f(n-2)
        f(n+5)
        f(n+7)
```

I need to count the unique numbers printed when f(0) is called.
First of all I tried to append each unique number to a list instead of printing all of them. But 'RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison' occured. Then I changed the value of sys.setrecursionlimit and my code started working but printed nothing:

```
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(2000000000)
lst = []
def f(n):
    if n not in lst:
        lst.append(n)
    if (0 <= n) and (n <= 1000000000):
        f(n-2)
        f(n+5)
        f(n+7)

f(0)
print(len(lst))
```

What should I do to solve the problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tracking the number of recursive calls without using global variables in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14513717/tracking-the-number-of-recursive-calls-without-using-global-variables-in-python)

Comment: you probably don't want to set recursion limit to that high, I can imagine that part of the issue why nothing is printing out is because it will take _"years"_ to complete that recursion and only then will it print out anything also your function is not printing out anything itself anyways

Comment: "But 'RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison' occured. Then I changed the value of sys.setrecursionlimit and my code started working but printed nothing:" Why did you change the recursion limit?

Comment: as jussi said, this is probably better solve with pen and paper, for example you can know at a glance that you would get all multiples of 5 and 7 with your initial n=0, because of f(n+5) and f(n+7) respectively, and then you also get all those number -2 too, and all multiple of 12 (5+7), and so on, so the problem could be reformulate as find all number x that could be written as x=5a+7b-2c for some a,b,c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code looks like it's going to blow up no matter the recursion depth, since the number of calls increases exponentially with the iterations. (Some of them won't result in further calls, such as `f(n-2)` on the first iteration, but most will). Which means that after a few dozen iterations, the interpreter might already have billions of calls to keep track of.

To me it looks more like a mathematical puzzle that could maybe be solved with pen and paper. Running the code doesn't seem to be feasible.

Comment: Ok, but how to count the unique numbers then? Also there's answer options below the task : a) 314285714
b) 314285716
c) 342857143
d) 342857145
e) 500000000
f) 500000002
g) 1000000000
h) 1000000008
i) 1000000010

Comment: Maybe the question is intentionally framed so that you cannot solve it by running Python code? Then you just have to think and figure out how `f()` gets called at each stage and what are the possible resulting values for `n`.

Answer (score 0):

This problem definitely isn't to test whether you have a supercomputer. The answer is 10^9 + 10.

This is because all numbers from 0 to 10^9 are printed at least once, overall printing `10^9 + 1` distinct numbers.

Call on f(1) prints a `-1`, f(0) prints a `-2`. `2` numbers below 0 are printed here.

f(10^9 - i) for i in 0...6 will print a number above 10^9 at least once, in total printing `7` numbers above 10^9.

Thus, total number of distinct numbers printed will be `10^9 + 1` + `2` + `7` = `1000000010`

If you find any other solutions, please let me know.

Comment: The solution that i found is very simple and not accurate, but here it is: I optimized my code a bit, so that it could work up to the n <= 1000 and I checked the output for different conditions in this string `if (0 <= n) and (n <= 1000000000):` and saw that for n<=100 the output is 110, for n<=1000 the output is 1010 and I assumed that for n <= 1000000000 the answer must be 100...0010 and the only suitable answer option below the task was just 1000000010